# com.linkedin.dex.spec.DexException: invalid LEB128 sequence

Tags: android, dex

We are getting the following exception when running the DexParser via Flank:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.linkedin.dex.spec.DexException: invalid LEB128 sequence
at com.linkedin.dex.spec.Leb128$Companion.readUnsignedLeb128(Leb128.kt:26)
at com.linkedin.dex.parser.DecodedValue$Companion.create(DecodedValue.kt:56)
at com.linkedin.dex.parser.AnnotationUtilsKt.getTestAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.kt:70)
at com.linkedin.dex.parser.AnnotationUtilsKt.getClassAnnotationValues(AnnotationUtils.kt:46)
at com.linkedin.dex.parser.TestMethodKt.createTestMethods(TestMethod.kt:42)
at com.linkedin.dex.parser.JUnit4ExtensionsKt.findAllJUnit4Tests(JUnit4Extensions.kt:35)
at com.linkedin.dex.parser.DexParser$Companion.findTestMethods(DexParser.kt:60)
at com.linkedin.dex.parser.DexParser$Companion.findTestNames(DexParser.kt:45)
at com.linkedin.dex.parser.DexParser$Companion.main(DexParser.kt:36)
at com.linkedin.dex.parser.DexParser.main(DexParser.kt)
```

A screenshot of the environment when this exception is hit is included below. How would I debug this exception/what would cause this issue?

[image]